# Hide output from stdClass Object

Tags: php, arrays, json

It would be great if someone could help me with a small problem, unfortunately I'm not familiar with it

```
public function userType($uid = null, $name = null) {
    $postfields = array(
        "username" => APIUSER,
        "password" => md5(APIPASS),
        "action" => 'getuser',
        "responsetype" => "json"
    );

    $arr = $this->callAPI($postfields);
```

the result

```
    stdClass Object
(
    [result] => success
    [totalresults] => 3
    [user] => stdClass Object
        (
            [user] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [uid] => 1
                            [gid] => 1
                            [status] => retired
                            [name] => John Doe

                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [pid] => 2
                            [gid] => 1
                            [status] => died
                            [name] => Jane Doe
                        )
                        
                    [2] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [pid] => 2
                            [gid] => 1
                            [type] => active
                            [name] => Frank Doe
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

How can i hide the result if [status] is 'retired' or 'died'?

Many, many thanks in advance

Comment: Do you just want to eliminate the status or the entire record?

Comment: [0] => stdClass Object and  [1] => stdClass Object terminate the rest should be returned

Answer (score 2):

This might work:

```
// ...
$arr = $this->callAPI($postfields);
foreach ($arr->user->user as &$tmpUser) {
    if (isset($tmpUser->status) && in_array($tmpUser->status, ['died' , 'retired'])) {
        unset($tmpUser->status);
    }
}
// ...
```

update: according to Jersons comment

update: according to Yoshis comment

Comment: if( in_array($arr->user->user[$index]->status,['died','retired'] ) )

Comment: Why access the array per `$index`? You could do all the work on the inappropriately named `$useless` variable... E.g. `if(isset($useless->status)...`.

Comment: That would work only if it was passed by as reference. Is that the case? If so i didnt know

Comment: With it being an instance of `stdClass` it's a reference. And even if not, you could do `foreach ($arr->user->user as &$notSoUselessActually) {...}` making it explict.

Comment: but this only removes the status [status] nd not the whole object

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove the status field only:

```
$arr = $this->callAPI($postfields);
$arr->user->user = array_map(function($user) {
    if (!empty($user['status']) && in_array($user['status'], ['died', 'retired'])) {
        unset($user['status']);
    }
    return $user;
}, $arr->user->user);
```

If you want to remove the entire user record:

```
$arr = $this->callAPI($postfields);
$arr->user->user = array_values(array_filter($arr->user->user, function($user) {
    return empty($user['status']) || !in_array($user['status'], ['died', 'retired']);
}));
```